# What is wrong with my jquery javascript here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

So I'm attempting to make a page in Visualforce(salesforce's page creator), and am having issues with the javascript aspect of it. Basically what should happen is that the  section will generate a series of links. The javascript needs to click those links. I'm using jquery

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="maininvoice">

<apex:repeat value="{!theListOfIDs}" var="anId">
 <apex:outputLink target="_blank" value="{!URLFOR($Page.invoice2,anId)}" styleClass="name" />
</apex:repeat>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(){

var anchortags = j$('.name');

            for(i=0;i<=anchortags.length;i++){
                var currentTag=anchortags[i];                        
                    currentTag.trigger(click);
                    alert("your mother");
                    }
            }
            );

</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It would really help you to figure out one problem at a time. Try creating a test page with your javascript. Once you get your javascript working, then put it into the salesforce environment.

The Salesforce tags and such here are really just extra noise that makes this look more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your exact question, this: `currentTag.trigger(click);` should be: `currentTag.trigger('click');`

But, come on, `jQuery` can do this all for you in one shot:

```
$('.name').click();
```

Comment: the thing is, currentTag is going to be a DOM element reference I think, so if he wanted it to work he'd need to write `$(currentTag).trigger('click');` - but he really can avoid the loop altogether because jQuery is happy to do it for him. I guess it's nice however that this incorrect answer is getting you upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

You're sort-of mixing up jQuery coding with "traditional" coding, and it's not working. Try this:

```
var anchortags = j$('.name');

anchortags.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(function(){
    j$('.name').click();
});
```

`j$(function(){...});` is the same as `j$(document).ready(function(){...});`

The `click()` function will be executed for every match in the previous list (`j$('.name')`). Use of `.each(function(){...});` is therefor redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function(){
   j$('.name').each(function() {
       j$(this).trigger('click');
   });
```